# MySql last record from group by item_id with order by date

Tags: mysql, sql, date, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

My database table name is ledgers and fields are **id, item_id, date, ...other fields**

I Want the ***last record from*** (***groupBy item_id order by date ASC***). from each group.
I tried below query

```
select 
    `id`, 
    `item_id`, 
    `date`, 
    `opening_quantity`, 
    `closing_quantity`, 
    `item_rate`, 
    `item_value`, 
    `previous_rate` 
from `ledgers` 
where date(`date`) >= ? and date(`date`) <= ? 
group by `item_id` 
order by `date` desc
```

Can you guys please help.

Comment: Is it possible that there are 2 entries for the same item_id on the same date?

Comment: yes same item_id, same date multiple times.

Comment: My query is above. but that is not correct I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from `ledgers` t
where 
    date(t.`date`) >= ? 
    and date(t.`date`) <= ?
    and t.`date` = (
        select max(t1.`date`)
        from `ledgers` t1
        where t1.`item_id` = t.`item_id`
    )
```

For performance, consider an index on `(item_id, date)`.

Another option is to use `rank()` (available in MySQ 8.0 only):

```
select * 
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by `item_id` order by `date` desc) rn
    from `ledgers` t
    where  date(t.`date`) >= ? and date(t.`date`) <= ?
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @GMB for your quick response.

Comment: I don't have much knowledge on **row_number()** and **rank()** too let me try..

Comment: Welcome @ThataL! `rank()` is a window function, it is available in MySQL 8.0 only. I provided that as an additional solution, however for your use case I find that the solution that uses a correlated subquery is more readable (and possibly more efficient).

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't.`date` = (
        select max(t1.`date`)
        from `ledgers` t1
        ' at line 6

Comment: typo: missing `and` keyword... fixed

Comment: Welcome @ThataL! Glad that it helped.